# jquery and styles not working when requested with ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have FAQ Page where I am showing FAQs based on category. When I load the page first time, FAQ slide up and slide down is working fine, but when I click on others tabs for  category search, then those FAQs are shown up, but no js and css is working.

Here is my FAQ page code:

```
<div class="faq-ajax-wrapper">

  <ul class="accordion-list">
    <?php 
      $faq_count = 1;
      $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'faq', 
        'posts_per_page' => -1, 
        'orderby' => 'date', 
        'order' => 'desc',
      );  

      $query = new WP_Query( $args );

      // The Loop
      if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
          while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
              $query->the_post();
      ?>
      <li>
        <h3><span class="bullet"><?php echo $faq_count++; ?></span> <?php the_title(); ?></h3>
        <div class="answer">
          <?php the_content(); ?>  
        </div>
      </li>
      <?php } } wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
    </ul>
</div>
```

JS code for the FAQ

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery('.accordion-list > li > .answer').hide();

  jQuery('.accordion-list > li').click(function() {
    alert('test');
    if (jQuery(this).hasClass("active")) {
      jQuery(this).removeClass("active").find(".answer").slideUp();
    } else {
      jQuery(".accordion-list > li.active .answer").slideUp();
      jQuery(".accordion-list > li.active").removeClass("active");
      jQuery(this).addClass("active").find(".answer").slideDown();
    }
    // return false;
  });
  
});
</script>
```

Here is my AJAX code

```
jQuery(".faq-tabs .faq-filter").on("click", function(){
    jQuery('.faq-tabs .faq-filter.active').removeClass('active');
    jQuery(this).addClass('active');
    faqHandler();
});

jQuery.fn.keyupDelay = function( cb, delay ){
    if(delay == null){
      delay = 400;
    }
    var timer = 0;
    return $(this).on('keyup',function(){
       clearTimeout(timer);
       timer = setTimeout( cb , delay );
    });
}

jQuery("#faq-search").keyupDelay( faqHandler );

function faqHandler() {
    var faq_tabs = $( '.faq-tabs .faq-filter.active' ).data("category-id");
    var faq_search = $( '#faq-search' ).val();
    faqdata = {
        'action': 'filter_faqs',
        'faq_tabs': faq_tabs,
        'faq_search': faq_search
    };
    jQuery.ajax({
        url : blog.ajaxurl,
        data : faqdata,
        type : 'POST',
        beforeSend : function ( xhr ) {
            $('.faq-loader').css( 'display', 'block' );
        },
        success : function( faqdata ) {
            if ( faqdata ) {
                $('.faq-loader').css( 'display', 'none' );
                $('.faq-ajax-wrapper').html( faqdata.faqposts );
            } else {
                $('.faq-loader').css( 'display', 'none' );
                $('.faq-ajax-wrapper').html( 'No posts found.' );
            }
        }
    });
}

function ajax_filter_faqs_handler() {
    $faq_category = esc_attr( $_POST['faq_tabs'] );
    $faq_search = esc_attr( $_POST['faq_search'] );

    $faq_args = array(
        'post_type' => 'faq',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'orderby' => 'date',
        'order' => 'DESC',
    );

    if ( $faq_category != 'all' ) {
        $faq_args['tax_query'] = array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'faq_category',
                'field'    => 'id',
                'terms'    => $faq_category,
            ),
        );
    }    

    if ( $faq_search != '' ) {
        $faq_args['s'] = $faq_search;
    } 

    $faqposts = 'No posts found.';
    $faq_count = 1;
    $faq_query = new WP_Query( $faq_args );
    if ( $faq_query->have_posts() ) :
        ob_start(); ?>
        <ul class="accordion-list">
        <?php while ( $faq_query->have_posts() ) : $faq_query->the_post(); ?>

        <li>
          <h3><span class="bullet"><?php echo $faq_count++; ?></span> <?php the_title(); ?></h3>
          <div class="answer">
            <?php the_content(); ?>  
          </div>
        </li>
            
        <?php endwhile; ?>
        </ul>
        <?php $faqposts = ob_get_clean();
    endif; wp_reset_postdata();

    $return = array(
        'faqposts' => $faqposts
    );

    wp_send_json($return);
}

add_action( 'wp_ajax_filter_faqs', 'ajax_filter_faqs_handler' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_filter_faqs', 'ajax_filter_faqs_handler' );
```

Basically I have tabs like All, Tech, Food. And I am using ajax to filter it. The problem is that FAQ JS and CSS is not working at all on ajax request.

Comment: I see you have hidden your accordion list at JS Code for the FAQ with : jQuery('.accordion-list > li > .answer').hide();

Where have you made it visible back again?

Comment: If you read the next lines, it is shown on click. But when I request with Ajax, even the alert is not working when I click on FAQ, however when I normally load and click, alert works fine.

Comment: Can you  like setup your code on JSFiddle so that it can be tested?

Comment: Are you saying that the slide up / down isn't working on the ajax refreshed content?

Comment: Yes, I have fixed it.

Comment: Is there any way to improve the keup event, because every time a key like shift, ctrl is up it is firing ajax. Also I don't want to run on empty spaces or backspace (when there is no letter), but when a user clears the word, then it should run to go back to return all search results.

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me.

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery('.accordion-list > li > .answer').hide();


  jQuery('body').on('click','.accordion-list > li',function(){
  // jQuery('.accordion-list > li').click(function() {
    if (jQuery(this).hasClass("active")) {
      jQuery(this).removeClass("active").find(".answer").slideUp();
    } else {
      jQuery(".accordion-list > li.active .answer").slideUp();
      jQuery(".accordion-list > li.active").removeClass("active");
      jQuery(this).addClass("active").find(".answer").slideDown();
    }
     return false;
  });
  
});
</script>
```